# How to get query output in Hive?

Tags: hive, oozie-workflow

I run a query from Oozie workflow:

```
select * from hivetable limit=5;
```

The query successfully executed but in the logs I can't see output of the select query.

[image: query output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got why output of SQL query is not showing.
Put a new line after last command in your .sql file and REMOVE all new lines within a query. Means your query should not contain any new line, when query finishes add a new line and add another query if you want to.